# Can we call winhttp request in UMDF driver successfully?

Tags: http, http-post, umdf

I have a problem in working with **WinHttp** request in my UMDF driver.

Whenever I call my `POST` method in  my REST API thread function, after the response is received, I get error 997

> Overlapped I/O operation is in progress

and my REST API thread stops and the driver restarts.